# reactjs: state properties are undefined after changing values

Tags: reactjs

After changing username and password in the inputs, the properties of my state become 'undefined'. I just can't get my head around it: for some reason this.setState doesn't seem to work.

This is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as LogonStore from '../store/LogonStore';

type LogonProps =
    LogonStore.LogonState
    & typeof LogonStore.actionCreators
    & RouteComponentProps<{}>;

class Logon extends React.Component<any, any> {
    public constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { un: '', pw: '' };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);      
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value); // works fine
        this.setState({ un: event.target.un, pw: event.target.pw });
        console.log(this.state); //first  un: '', pw: '' then un: undefined, pw: undefined
    }

    public render() {
        return <div >
            <h1>Logon</h1>
            <label>username</label><input value={this.state.un} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label>password</label><input value={this.state.pw} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <br />         
        </div>;
    }
}


export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.logon, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
    LogonStore.actionCreators                 // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
)(Logon) as typeof Logon;
```

I'm missing something fundamental here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only handle the change of one input at a time. Here is the problem code:

```
this.setState({ un: event.target.un, pw: event.target.pw });
```

When you type in a form field, your `handleChange` function will get called. The `event.target` is the HTML input element of the thing you just changed... meaning you cannot update the values for both username and password at the same time like you're trying to do. You can only update values one at a time. In order to facilitate this, you will need to add a "name" property to your input elements:

```
<input name="un" value={this.state.un} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input name="pw" value={this.state.pw} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Then update your state like this:

```
this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. My code wasn't that foolish.

Comment: Could you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153957/value-becomes-undefined-because-of-setstate/67154970#67154970

Answer (score 2):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      un:'',
      pw:''
    }
  }
  
  handleChange=(event)=> {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value}, 
    () => {
      //updated state
      console.log(this.state)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1> Logon </h1> 
      <label> username </label>
      <input name="un" value={this.state.un} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      <br /> 
      <label> password </label>
      <input name="pw" value={this.state.pw} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
    </div>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Explanation as asked by OP:

**setState is asynchronous**. 
It takes time to mutate the changes. So instead of checking state on next immediate line, you can log or check it as shown in the answer.
For more detailed information on this please refer **[setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**

Comment: The abundance of copy/paste code out there with no explanation is likely why to OP doesn't understand why their code isn't working. Please try and help the person understand _why_ their code doesn't work.

Comment: @RyanWheale, sure, I was about to edit the answer after posting the code. But saw you answer and stopped as it had explanation, and I didn't copy and paste.

Comment: @OleEHDufour, I have updated the answer, with the link for more info.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that _you_ copied and pasted. You provided a code-only answer. It does no good to only provide code for the OP to copy/paste. Thanks for updating with an explanation.

Comment: Could you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153957/value-becomes-undefined-because-of-setstate/67154970#67154970

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an asynchronous function. Thus, you cannot access it on the next line, but I assure you it's working. Also, if you really want to log the values from state you can either put the log inside the render method OR use the setState callback, which is the second argument of the `setState` function, like so:

```
this.setState(
  { un: event.target.value.un, pw: event.target.value.pw },
  () => console.log(this.state)
);
```

Comment: wouldn't they be strings still instead of undefined?